# How do I Deserialize OData JSON Error Message?

Tags: c#, json, odata

I'm trying to deserialize this odata error message:

[image]

The object members are always null for this code:

```
    public static async Task<ExceptionResponse> ExceptionResponse(this HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
    {
        string responseContent = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExceptionResponse>(responseContent);
        return exceptionResponse;
    }
}

public class ExceptionResponse
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionType { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }
    public ExceptionResponse InnerException { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get the error message and innererror message?

Comment: The class that you created doesn't match with JSON structure

Comment: How should the class look? All my attempts at changing it our failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public class InnerError {
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }
}

public class Error {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public InnerError InnerError { get; set; }
}

public class ExceptionResponse {
    public Error Error { get; set; }
}
```